# Trying to use sudo in WSL but my Microsoft account (which I'm logged into as Admin on Windows 10) password won't work. How can I fix it?

Tags: password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I look into what my admin password is on Windows 10, everything seems to point to it being linked to the Microsoft account I have connected.

I validated this, it seems to be the case that I am not currently using a local account:

[image]

But the same password I'm able to use to log into this Microsoft account with does not work when I attempt to run `sudo` in WSL. There is only one account on my PC.

What detail have I missed or how can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) password is not your Windows password. To change your WSL password, try the following steps.

On a Windows prompt, enter the command:

```
wsl --user root
```

You should be logged in as root into your WSL. Now, use the `passwd` command to change the password for your user:

```
passwd username
```

Replace `username` with your actual Linux username.

You will be asked to type a new password without being asked for the current one. Once you're done, just leave the session with `exit`. Your user's password should have been changed.

**Source:** [How To Reset Your Forgotten Linux Password in WSL (CloudSavvyIT)](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/13657/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-linux-password-in-wsl/)

Comment: Can be simplified to just `wsl -u root passwd <username>`

Comment: I'm getting "user not found".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know your password, type `passwd` at the prompt and you can change your password.

Your Ubuntu password is not the same as your Windows password.

Comment: When I type `passwd`, it asks for my current password.